# ArrayList duplicating entries?

Tags: android, json, arraylist

In my application I have a JSON that contain a JSONArray into a JSONObject. I picked up these JSONObject with JSONArray and generate an object Batalha and also picked up JSONArray("badges") and add into object BadgesGanha. In object Batalha I have a List that I add the objects BadgeGanha.

Now I'm trying print the size of List in object Batalha, the problem is that print a duplicate value, for example if List has size 3 in logcat print 6. I can't understand why this problem.

**JSON**

```
"retorno": {
        "batalhas": {
            "aberto": [
                {
                    "ID": "17",
                    "player1": "fernando@domain.com",
                    "player2": "joao@msn.com",
                    "data_inicio": "2014-12-05 16:32:03",
                    "data_fim": null,
                    "status": "1",
                    "ID_arena": "1",
                    "vez_player": "joao@msn.com",
                    "player_vencedor": null,
                    "adversario": [
                        {
                            "ID": "9",
                            "nome": "Joao Paulo",
                            "email": "joao@msn.com",
                            "foto": "e8357f1a1d05334f08c84d2de0049234.png",
                            "status": "1",
                            "online": "0",
                            "pontuacao": "1260",
                            "graduacao": "Ministro"
                        }
                    ],

                    "badges": [
                        {
                            "ID": "41",
                            "email": "joao@msn.com",
                            "ID_batalha": "17",
                            "ID_arena": "1",
                            "status": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "ID": "45",
                            "email": "fernando@domain.com",
                            "ID_batalha": "17",
                            "ID_arena": "1",
                            "status": "0"
                        },
                        {
                            "ID": "51",
                            "email": "fernando@domain.com",
                            "ID_batalha": "17",
                            "ID_arena": "1",
                            "status": "0"
                        },

                    ]
                },
```

**Bean**

```
public class Batalha implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SerializedName("ID")
    private Long id;

    private String player1;
    private String player2;
    private String data_inicio;
    private String data_fim;
    private int status;
    private int ID_arena;
    private String vez_player;
    private String player_vencedor;

    private List<BadgesGanha> badges = new ArrayList<BadgesGanha>();


    public Batalha() {    
    }


    /** add badges ganha */
    public void addBadgesGanha(BadgesGanha badge){
        badges.add(badge);
    }



public class BadgesGanha implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SerializedName("ID")
    private Integer id;

    private String email;
    private Integer ID_batalha;
    private Integer ID_arena;
    private Integer status;
```

**Creating a List and display size of List**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JSONObject objRetorno = obj.getJSONObject("retorno");

/** abertas */
JSONObject objBatalhas = objRetorno.getJSONObject("batalhas");
JSONArray arrayAberto = objBatalhas.getJSONArray("aberto");
List<Batalha> listBatalhaAberta = new ArrayList<Batalha>();

//batalha aberta
for(int x = 0; x < arrayAberto.length(); x++){
    //pega batalha
    JSONObject jsObj = arrayAberto.getJSONObject(x);
    Batalha batalha = gson.fromJson(jsObj.toString(), Batalha.class);

    //pega badges
    JSONArray arrayBadges = jsObj.getJSONArray("badges");
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayBadges.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jsBadge = arrayBadges.getJSONObject(i);
        BadgesGanha badge = gson.fromJson(jsBadge.toString(), BadgesGanha.class);
        //add badge batalha
        batalha.addBadgesGanha(badge);
    }
    //create list of Batalha
    listBatalhaAberta.add(batalha);
}

//print size list List<BadgesGanha>
for(Batalha x : listBatalhaAberta){
   //should print 3 badges but print 6 badges
   Log.i("BADGES LISTBATALHAABERTA-> ", x.getBadges().size() + "");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I change block badge and now works !

```
//badges
JSONArray arrayBadges = jsObj.getJSONArray("badges");
List<BadgesGanha> lista = new ArrayList<BadgesGanha>();
for(int i = 0; i < arrayBadges.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsBadges = arrayBadges.getJSONObject(i);
    BadgesGanha badge = gson.fromJson(jsBadges.toString(), BadgesGanha.class);
    lista.add(badge);
    batalha.setBadges(lista);
}
```